# Why does my If-Else never evaluate to true?

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement

I'm supposed to count the number of times variable integer "num" divided by each of its digit results in a clean quotient (has a remainder of 0).

Note: Each digit is considered to be unique, so each occurrence of the same evenly divisible digit should be counted (i.e.: for 222, the answer is 3).

```
int solver(int num) //gets an integer
{
    string numString = to_string(num); //convert integer to string so i can manipulate individual digits
    int divisible=0; //will store a count of digits in "num" which can be divided evenly

    for (int x = 1; x <= (end(numString) - begin(numString))/*string length*/; x++)
    {

        if (numString[x-1] == 0 || (end(numString) - begin(numString))-x >=1) //ignore digits which are 0 and or 0s that are last in the array
            ++x;

        if (num % numString[x - 1] == 0) //THIS NEVER EVALUATES TO TRUE. HOW COME???
            divisible++; 

    }
    return divisible;  //number of digits in variable "num" which can be evenly divided
}
```

This function ALWAYS returns 0 (that's what variable int "divisible was initialized to), because the if-else for incrementing it always evaluates to false and is skipped. I have checked and made sure the If-Else arguments hold valid numbers (they're all integers). Is it because they are all integers that the decimal part of the result never reach If-Else for evaluation? That's the best possibility I can come up with, and even then I don't know how to remedy.

Comment: You have a string. Strings contains characters. Characters (even if they are digits) are not numbers. `0 != '0'`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? You could create a variable ```int test = num % numString[x - 1];``` and take a look at what test equals

Comment: @VictorTran i used 222 for num and test returned 22, which is..weird

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can I cleanly turn those strings to ints?

Comment: Slightly OT but there are easier way to obtain the digits of a number without using `std::string`, see e.g. http://ideone.com/Sldt9G.

Comment: @Holt that's a painful way to solve this for a beginner, mate. I kick myself for taking so long to understand code that does so little

Comment: @WillNjundong I don't think it is more painful than yours (but I admit I could have split some instructions to make it clearer for beginners) - Your code involves iterators, array-like object (`std::string`) and conversion between digit characters and integer (`'0' - 0`) - My code only involves simple `for` loop and simple arithmetic. I would need some chapters of any C++ books to understand your code, while the first chapter of any of these covers everything needed to understand mine.

Comment: @Holt well said. I agree with your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. learn about [size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) function of `std::string`. You don't need `end` and `begin` to get the length of a `string`.
2. `numString[x-1]` returns a `char` an ASCII code, not the digit as numeric value. The ASCII code of `0` in decimal for example is `48`. To get the numeric value of a single digit you could do:
   `numString[x-1] - '0'`

Comment: I think I tried something like that earlier, along with *variable*.length and got unreasonable numbers. I assume they were memory sizes or something, from what i learned online

Comment: `string::length` returns the *The number of bytes in the string* same as `size()`. A link to [length doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/). You would get the *memory size* by `string::capacity`